# How to make custom help for each page in SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, help

We have SharePoint site with a lot of pages. One step in our project development is creating custom help for each page. After a user clicks "Help" icon in top of each page, help page opens and shows only that page's help content.

How can I customize SharePoint help desk to do this for each page?

Answer (score 0):

In a long run it'll probably not be a good idea to have a custom help for each of your "many pages", as you said. Some reasoning at the end of the answer.

SharePoint offers a rather simple solution of creating a custom help in a site collection scope, which is a more standard solution. The key is to activate the `Custom Site Collection Help` site collection feature. Further reading at [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-custom-help-to-a-site-collection-fa9faf46-9cb1-4804-a890-4f17ec01910f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Why not to create a custom solution for this? Sure it's possible in a way or another. You, however, should need to consider at least the (automatic) help page creation, a possible blank help page, how it would replace the OOTB help-button and possible search issues with similar looking pages based on title/content.